# Linq query in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have some xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<carLot>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicleType>Car</vehicleType>
        <color>Red</color>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicleType>Truck</vehicleType>
        <color>Black</color>
        <transmissionType>Automatic</transmissionType>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <vehicleType>Car</vehicleType>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <transmissionType>Manual</transmissionType>
    </vehicle>
</carLot>
```

I am trying to grab the vehicle nodes that are of type Car. What I currently have returns each vehicle node:

```
XElement test = XElement.Load(fileName);
var testThing = from thing in test.Descendants("vehicle")
                select thing;
```

Comment: your query is doing what you told it to - it's grabbing all the "Vehicle" nodes.  You need to check if "vehicleType" is the type you're looking for, using a where clause - `var testThing = from thing in test.Descendants("vehicle") where (string)testThing.Element("vehcileType") == "Car" select thing;`

Comment: I am getting the error "cannot use local variable "testThing" before it is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without converting to Lambda expressions, you can do:

```
    XElement test = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xml));
    var testThing = from thing in test.Descendants("vehicle")
                    where thing.Descendants("vehicleType").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString() == "Car"
                    select thing;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Tim's comment to the question (using Lambda Expressions):

```
var testThing = test.Descendants("vehicle")
    .Where(c=>(string)c.Element("vehcileType")=="Car")
    .Select(c=>c);
```